# Is $T_{decay}$ the time it takes for an amount of radioactive nuclei to decay $\it{completely}$?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radioactivity, half-life

My friend told me about this idea.

Let there be $N_0$ atoms of a particular radioactive material. Then the number of atoms at time $t$, $N_t$, we already know, is given by:

$$N_t = N_0 e^{-t/\tau},\; where\; \tau = \frac{t_{1/2}}{\ln(2)}$$

where Half-life of the material: $t_{1/2}$.

Is the following quantity useful in any physics or nuclear engineering or something:

$$T_{decay} = \tau(1 + \ln{N_0}) = \dfrac{t_{1/2}}{\ln{2}} (1 + \ln{N_0})$$

This is basically the sum of the time it takes for the number of atoms/nuclei to reduce to $1$ and the mean lifetime of a single atom/nucleus.

Isn't $T_{decay}$ the time it takes for all nuclei to have decayed/changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$T_{decay}$ as you've defined it is a reasonable rough estimate of how long it will take before the last nucleus has decayed. However, you can't say that that's how long it will take for sure, because $N_t = N_0 e^{-t/\tau}$ is only accurate in a probabilistic sense.  Also, that expression for $N_t$ is only accurate when $N_t$ is large enough that it's reasonable to treat it as a real number instead of an integer.

You can get a more accurate value for $T_{decay}$ by treating the problem probabilistically explicitly:

Given that the probability that a given initially undecayed nucleus $i$ will remain undecayed after a period $t$ is given by
$$\bar{p}_i(t)=e^{-t/\tau}\ \ ,$$
the probability that all $N_0$ initially undecayed nuclei will have decayed after a period $t$ is given by
$$p(t)=\prod_{i=1}^{N_0}\left[1-\bar{p}_i(t)\right]=\left ( 1-e^{-t/\tau} \right )^{N_0}\ \ .$$
Solving that expression for $t$ gives that the time required for there to be a probability $p$ that all of the nuclei have decayed is
$$T_{decay}(p)=-\tau \ln \left ( 1-p^{1/N_0}\right )\ \ .$$

Note that that expression diverges in the limit $p \to 1$, reflecting the fact that you can never quite be 100% certain that all of the nuclei have decayed, no matter how long you wait.

The above can be related to the value of $T_{decay}$ given in the question by noting that

$$p\left(\tau(1+\ln N_0)\right)=\left(1-\frac{1}{e N_0}\right)^{N_0}\ \ .$$

For large $N_0$ this approaches

$$\lim_{N_0\to\infty}p\left(\tau(1+\ln N_0)\right)=e^{-1/e}=0.692201\ \ .$$

I.e., after a period of $T_{decay}$ as given in the question, there's about a 69.22% chance that all of the nuclei have decayed.

Comment: What is $p(\tau(1 + \ln{N_0}))$?

Comment: @PhyEnthusiast I have augmented my answer to address your follow-up question.

Comment: 1/(e^(1/e)) is so much better than 69.22%.  Which makes me want to figure out; how would I make a real question whose answer is 1/(e^(1/e^(1/...)))?  (I don't expect an answer)

Answer (score 0):

According to the cited decay law for the decay of a very large number of radioactive nuclei, there is no finite time until all nuclei will have decayed. You can chose any large time $t$ and you will always still have a finite number of undecayed nuclei. You haven't given an explanation how you arrive at this quantity $T_{decay}$. $T_{decay}$ doesn't seem to have any significance.

Note: The exponential decay law is a probabilistic law. You can take $N/N_0=e^{-t/\tau}$ to represent the probability at time $t$ that a single nucleus has not yet decayed. Therefore, even if you have only one nucleus, you cannot give a time until it will have decayed!

Comment: The OP is using the discrete nature of the number of nuclei and the fact that the continuous exponential approximation must break down once there are only a few nuclei left. They are saying that $\tau \ln N_0$ is the amount of time it takes for the expected number of nuclei to reach 1, and then the single additional $\tau$ is the time for that final nucleus to decay.

Comment: @tparker - The exponential decay law is a probabilistic law. You can take $N/N_0$ for the probability at time $t$ that a single nucleus has not yet decayed. Therefore, even if you have only one nucleus, you cannot give a time until it will have decayed.

Comment: I know, I was just clarifying their (incorrect) reasoning for you.

Comment: @tparker - Thank you for the explanation of the OP's reasoning.  You are right, I will extend my  answer.

Comment: @freecharly The formula only has $N_0$ because $N_t$ is taken to be $1$. As tparker put it, $\tau \ln N_0$ is the amount of time it takes for the expected number of nuclei to reach $1$, and then the single additional $\tau$ is the time for that final nucleus to decay. I have explained this within the question.

Comment: @PhyEnthusiast -You are right, in this case one can also use the log only of $N_0$. I will delete this sentence. Now, I also understand the calculation. As I explained in my answer, the derived time **$T_{decay}$ is not the time until all nuclei will have decayed**, because the decay law is only probabilistic. Even if you knew that only a single nucleus was left undecayed, you cannot give a time until it will have decayed for sure!